# not able to load entity after insertion in toplink

Tags: java, orm, toplink

i am using toplink as ORM tool, i am facing one peculiar problem. I am inserting an entity into the session and then in the next line if i try to load the same entity, i am unable to get that, instead it returns me null. But the same issue if i try using hibernate, then it works properly. can any one please help.

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setAddressId("1");
address.setPincode(1);
uow2.registerNewObject(address);
ExpressionBuilder builder = new ExpressionBuilder();
Expression expr = builder.get("addressId").equal("1");
Address address1 = (Address)uow2.readObject(Address.class, expr);
```

at the end i get address1 as null. i don't understand as i am inserting the object with the same key and then trying to retrieve it... plz help me...

Comment: Are you using JPA or TopLink API? And what are comparing exactly? AFAIK, TopLink's Session is not the same thing as Hibernate Session? Show some code might help actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Native TopLink/EclipseLink code.  You are only 'registering' the Address with the UnitOfWork which does not write out until committed.

There are a couple of ways to get uncommitted results from a UnitOfWork.  In the scenario above you can call uow.setShouldNewObjectsBeCached(true) before registering the new object then the readObject call will find it.

You can also change the readObject call to a ReadObjectQuery and set conformResultsInUnitOfWork on the query.

If you are just starting out with EclipseLink/TopLink then I recommend using the JPA APIs.  You will be able to find many resources on JPA.  Then once you begin to optimize your code or begin to tackle complicated scenarios you can use the EclipseLink mailing lists and forums to get EclipseLink specific assistance.